# Executing remote procedures on a schedule using pg_cron

Tags: postgresql, dblink, pg-cron

I need help figuring out how to execute remote procedures via db_link using pg_cron.

Below is the code for creating a db_link, adding a procedure call to pg_cron, and checking that the procedure is correctly executed via db_link in pgAdmin under the postgres user.

However, when the scheduler runs, it returns an error - `status: failed`, `return_message: "connection failed"`

How can I fix this issue and configure pg_cron to execute a remote procedure via dblink in PostgreSQL 15?

Here is the code I've tried:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dblink_dev', 'dbname=dev host=localhost user=fetcher password=password');

SELECT cron.schedule(
    'schedule_delete_old_data', 
    '1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * *', 
    $$SET statement_timeout = '4min 30s'; PERFORM dblink_exec('dblink_dev', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()'); SET statement_timeout = '0';$$
);  

SELECT dblink_exec('dblink_dev', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()');
```

The following variant also did not give a result and returned the same error.

```
SELECT cron.schedule(
    'schedule_delete_old_ohlcv_data', 
    '1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * *', 
    $$SET statement_timeout = '4min 30s'; PERFORM dblink('dbname=dev host=localhost user=fetcher password=password', 'CALL market.delete_old_history_data()');SET statement_timeout = '0';$$
);
```